# How to detect automatically a reCaptcha in an android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, recaptcha

So, i need to detect if in a webview is loaded a reCaptcha or not.
I don't know if i should do this with some java code or with a javascript injection. Here's my code:

```
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(paypal_url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            loadJs(view, js_1);

        }
    }
```

A simple Toast with a message like "reCaptcha loaded" would be great.